# Find the volume of the solid under the plane $x + 2y - z = 0$ and above the region bounded by $y=x$ and $y = x^4$.

Tags: calculus

Find the volume of the solid under the plane $x + 2y - z = 0$ and above the region bounded by $y = x$ and $y = x^4$.

$$
\int_0^1\int_{x^4}^x{x+2ydydx}\\
\int_0^1{x^2-x^8dx}\\
\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{9} = \frac{2}{9}
$$

Did I make a misstep? The answer book says I am incorrect.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wrote the question a bit wrong. I've updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\int_0^1\int_{x^4}^x{(x+2y)\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x}$ You have set correctly the integral but you did not integrate correctly.

Be careful in $\int_{x^4}^x{(x+2y)}\mathrm{d}y$ you integrate in respect of $y$ so you should find
$$\int_{x^4}^x{(x+2y)}\mathrm{d}y=\left | xy+y^2 \right |_{x^4}^{x}=x^2+x^2-(x^5+x^{8}) $$
And finally you get $\int_0^1 2x^2-x^5-x^{8}\mathrm{d}y=\frac{2}{3}-\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{9}=\frac{7}{18}$

You could verify your results [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=f5f3cbf14f4f5d6d2085bf2d0fb76e8a)

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be calculated as
\begin{eqnarray*}
V&=&\int_0^1\int_{x^4}^x\int_0^{x+2y}dzdydx\\
&=&\int_0^1\int_{x^4}^x(x+2y)dydx\\
&=&\int_0^1\left.\left(xy+y^2\right)\right|_{x^4}^xdx\\
&=&\int_0^1(2x^2-x^5-x^8)dx\\
&=&\left.(\frac{2}{3}x^3-\frac{1}{6}x^6-\frac{1}{9}x^9)\right|_0^1\\
&=&\frac{7}{18}
\end{eqnarray*}